# Transplanting mobo, different chipset

Tags: windows-7, motherboard

I have to change the motherboard. New mobo's chipset is different from previous one. Is it possible to simply transplant the mother board and repair the operating system installation? Any hint?

Thx

Details:

- OS: Win7 32bit
- previous mobo: Asus M2NPV-VM, chipset NVidia
- next mobo: Asus M3A78
- CPU: AMD Athlon 64 X2 6000+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, but not always, you can just swap out the mobo and Windows will figure things out.

Sometimes, however Windows will blue screen.  Often this is due to the previous mobo using a non-standard storage device driver, so if your old mobo is using any sort of special IDE driver (such as a RAID driver) it would be wise to uninstall this prior to swapping in the new motherboard.

Comment: Probably. Before switching, I'd make sure that all such controllers are disabled in the old motherboard's BIOS, then boot into Windows one last time to uninstall the drivers. If after replacing, you can't boot into Windows, a repair will likely fix things. If all else fails, fear not, because you will always still be able to recover your data.

Comment: This happened to me last time I switched out a motherboard. I just put a new hard drive in (making the original drive a secondary drive) and installed Windows on the new drive. Then copied the files off the old drive...

Comment: I just tried and Windows Seven worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a copy of Acronis True Image with universal restore you may have more success.  You create an image with the old mobo and then restore it to the new one.  It allows you to add needed drivers.  It has been successfully for me in the past at rebuilding the hal etc...